# Windowed mode emulator after Bumblebee update

Tags: android-studio

Today I updated my Android Studio from the Arctic Fox to Bumblebee 2021.1.1, and I realized my AVD and emulator windows changed a bit. They were on separate windows, now they are on the right side-menu.

I windowed the emulator again to get the old style, but the mobile-phone on the emulator is not separated from the menu. In the older version, I only had the phone as a separate window, I didn't have window bars and side fillers that are marked on the picture below. How can I get rid of them and only get the phone instead of the whole window? I don't want it as "emulator window" but rather plain "phone".

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want the old look in Arctic Fox, go to

**File->Settings->Tools->Emulator** and **unselect "Launch in a tool window".**

This way it will launch it seperately which is the same as in the old version.

Answer (score 1):

For **Mac** go to Android Studio **Preferences - Tools - Emulator** and uncheck Launch in a tool window.

[image]